# Pass a full bash script line to another bash function to execute

Tags: linux, bash, function, arguments

in the BASH code below, the variable ECHO_ALL is a global and set to either 'yes' or 'no' based on input parsing of options.

--- begin of ~/scripts/util/util-optout.sh ---

```
########################################
# @param    $@
# @return   the return value from $@
# @brief    A wrapper function to allow
#           for OPTional OUTput of any
#           command w/wo args
#######################################
optout()
{
    if [ ${ECHO_ALL} = 'no' ]; then
        "$@" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
        return $?
    else
        "$@"
        return $?
    fi
}
```

--- end of file ---

in another bash file I source the above util-optout.sh file and use the optout() function to allow for conditional output.. essentially allow for conditional redirection of any commands output to /dev/null to make scripts silent.

for example in some other build script i have

```
source ~/scripts/util/util-optout.sh

optout pushd ${ZLIB_DIR}
optout rm -vf config.cache

optout CC=${BUILD_TOOL_CC} ./configure ${ZLIB_CONFIGURE_OPT} --prefix=${CURR_DIR}/${INSTALL_DIR}
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#      ^ this breaks my optout() command
# my optout() fails when there are prefixed bash env vars set like CC=${...} before ./configure 

optout popd
optout make -C ${ZLIB_DIR} ${ZLIB_COMPILER_OPT} all
optout make -C ${ZLIB_DIR} install
```

for simple commands with any type of parameters after it like 'pushd' or 'rm'.. optout() works great.
even the optout make -C ones work fine.

but it gives me an error for commands that have prefix env-vars set like the optout CC=${...} ./configure ...

utils/util-optout.sh: line 33: CC=gcc: command not found

Is there a way to make my optout() function work for ANY possible valid bash script line.

i know it has something to do with the use of "$@" or "$*" in my optout() function, but i have studied the bash man pages in detail and I can't make it work for all possible bash line cases.

so far the only way to get past this limitation with my optout() is the following 3-line style; which is annoying.

```
export CC=${BUILD_TOOL_CC}
optout ./configure ${ZLIB_CONFIGURE_OPT} --prefix=${CURR_DIR}/${INSTALL_DIR}
unset CC
```

Any ideas on how to reduce it all back down to a single optout ... line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`optout` is a command like any other, and so must be preceded by any local modifications to the environment. The command that `optout` runs will inherit that environment.

```
CC=${BUILD_TOOL_CC} optout ./configure ${ZLIB_CONFIGURE_OPT} --prefix=${CURR_DIR}/${INSTALL_DIR}
```

By the way, this is just one of the problems you are likely to encounter with your `optout` function. You cannot run arbitrary command lines in that fashion, only a simple command followed by zero or more arguments (and I would expect there are some exceptions to even that restricted set, as well).

Comment: wow.. I have obviously been staring at this problem for to long to see  the forest from the trees!